# How to use Mutt as the mail transport agent used by crontab?

Tags: cron, email, mail, mutt

I am using [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org) to send emails from my server. Using the **MAILTO** variable to send the result of running crontab tasks is not working as it seems that it expects to find /usr/bin/mail.

This is the output of */var/log/mail.log* for a crontab job:

```
Nov 18 12:51:01 myserver postfix/sendmail[22649]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
```

I would like to avoid configuring any other mail servers (postfix, sendmail, etc).

Is there any way to make crontab use Mutt to send emails?